# Drag and Drop on touch screen Timeline

Tags: javascript, touch, tablet, vis.js, timeline.js

How can I drag items (not the items in the timeline) with touch screen on mobile into the timeline?

For example:

http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/other/drag&drop.html
the "item1 - box"

I want to drag the item1 to the timeline. It work very fine on desktop browser and the touch on the timeline work also on mobile

regards